# Use Criteria Query to get latest data record from database

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, criteria-api

How to get a latest record (row) from a database in JPA Criteria query?
I have used something like that. But i cannot do that?

```
 CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<Number> criteria = cb.createQuery(Number.class);
            Root<Icd> icds = criteria.from(Icd.class);
            criteria.select(cb.max(icds.<Number>get("icdsDate")));
            Object result=em.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
            System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$  "+result+"   $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
```

I want a Icd Object as a result.

Comment: Clarify why you cant?

Comment: i want to get a data record. that mean Icd Object to get it's value.

Comment: `"But i cannot do that?"` What do you mean by that? Compilation error? Wrong results??